# Dealing with "PHP HTML DOM Parser", including the same library into two different files

Tags: php, dom, syntax, html-parsing

I have two PHP files (same folders) that access the library `simple_html_dom.php`

The first one, `caridefine.php`has this:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = 'http://www.statistics.com/index.php?page=glossary&term_id=209';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($curl_scraped_page);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
print $xpath->evaluate('string(//p[preceding::b]/text())');
```

The second one, `caridefine2.php` has this:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = 'http://www.statsoft.com//textbook/statistics-glossary/z/?button=0#Z Distribution (Standard Normal)';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($curl_scraped_page);
foreach ($html->find('/p/a [size="4"]') as $font) {
    $link = $font->parent();
    $paragraph = $link->parent();
    $text = str_replace($link->plaintext, '', $paragraph->plaintext);
    echo $text;
}
```

Separately, each of them worked fine, I ran the `caridefine.php`, it worked well, so did the `caridefine2.php`.
But when I tried to load these two files in other PHP files:

```
        <div class="examples">
            <?php
                $this->load->view('definer/caridefine.php');
            ?>
        </div>

        <div class="examples">
            <?php
               $this->load->view('definer/caridefine2.php');
            ?>
        </div>
```

None of them worked. Just gave me a blank page, when I pressed `CTRL+U`, it said: `Cannot redeclare file_get_html() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\MSPN\APPLICATION\views\Definer\simple_html_dom.php:70) in C:\xampp\htdocs\MSPN\APPLICATION\views\Definer\simple_html_dom.php on line 85`

I googled for this problem, I found that "if you load many objects without clearing the previous ones, it can be a problem."
I've tried doing `$html->clear()` and `unset($dom)`. It gave me nothing.
What is it that makes me like in the end of the line?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried analyse my own problem:
Here is the correction:

Change `include('simple_html_dom.php');` in each file into: `require_once('simple_html_dom.php');`

What happened was the file called the file `simple_html_dom.php` twice. So it won't work.
That should do it.

Comment: For reference: [What is the difference between PHP require and include?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3626265/367456)

Comment: Please accept your answer to mark the question as solved. Also I don't  think your question is directly related to the memory leak of that library, so please correct the title so that it's not misleading when searched for. Thank you!

Comment: Yea, it said to me that I could only accept my answer two days later (which is today), and still have to wait for 11 hours from now. How do I change the title with?

Comment: A right, there are these periods. I just noted, sometimes users don't see they can do so I leave a note. :) - You can change your questions title by editing the question.

Comment: No, my question is not how to technically do that, but 'what sentence will best replace the title of this question'? ^^