# Using a PHP file within another PHP file

Tags: php, menu

I've created a menu on the upper part of the page (in PHP). Now I would like all pages to contain it but I don't want to use frames and i prefer not to use <<< / EOF to edit the menu content.

Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: can you post some sample code for this ?

Comment: Have you tried `include()`?

Comment: Did you google "php include file"?

Comment: @SagiLow `include("header.php");`

Comment: `include()` includes another file inside a file.

Comment: start from php.net  not from SO .. please  http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: php: include, require_once. Or you can also include the menu using javascript/jquery ajax when the page loads.

Comment: this is going to be the epic battle of answers to the question "how to include a PHP file" question .. anyone up for a [pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(programming_language)) version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use PHP [`include()`](http://php.net/include):

```
<?php
include('menu.php');

//rest of your code goes here
```

---

The other alternatives are:

- `require()`
- `require_once()`
- `include_once()`

[`require()`](http://php.net/require)

The require() function is identical to `include()`, except that it handles errors differently. If an error occurs, the `include()` function generates a warning, but the script will continue execution. The `require()` generates a fatal error, and the script will stop.

[`require_once()`](http://php.net/require_once)

The `require_once` statement is identical to require except PHP will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again.
If in doubt, read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2418514/1438393).

[`include_once()`](http://php.net/include_once)

The `include_once` statement includes and evaluates the specified file during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the include statement, with the only difference being that if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again.

If you're confused about which one to use, check out these answers:

**[#2418473](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/)
[#3626235](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626235/)
[#11051219](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051219/)**

Hope this helps!

Comment: No idea, but I +1'd, maybe you could also add `require_once/include_once`?

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`include`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) (or `require`):

```
... stuff before the menu

<?php include 'menu.php'; ?>

... rest of my page here
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question asks for "any other way to do this" and since php include and require has already been proposed, here is another way using javascript (jquery):

```
<html>
<head>
... (meta tags etc.)
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        $('#menu').load('menu.php');
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='menu'></div>
    ... (page content etc)
</body>
</html>
```