# How to get codes from another page? (Basic PHP)

Tags: php

I want something like Wordpress's system. I want to get **header** code from header.php so I will not have to edit all of the pages when I'm going to edit something.

Comment: You want to [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) some code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between PHP require and include?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626235/what-is-the-difference-between-php-require-and-include)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never get the code because one the php page is render, it gets converted into HTML so you will always see html.

I understand, you need header component.

```
 1)Create a file header.php (add navigation bar or logo or whatever you want).

 2)Include it in other php files as include("header.php");
```

so all the pages will be using this one `header.php` file and you can modify it and the changes would get reflected all over the web app.

Comment: It's worked. By the way, for noobs like me you have to use it in between <?php and ?>  <?php includecodehere ?>

Comment: include is a php function so you will have to open the tags to use it..